# Google Spreadsheet script, file access in Drive, "You do not have permission to call ..."

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a Sheet where I need to get the id of a file located in my Google-drive.
I have written the folowing script:

```
function get_id_pdf() {
  var nom='INV432-altaïr-Famille XXX-XXX Marie-03-2016.pdf';
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("'"+nom+"'");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var type = file.getMimeType();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    var id = file.getId();
    // Logger.log(file.getId());
    return file.getId();
  }
}
```

If I execute it in the Script editor (with the `run` button), it is working well (I get the id the the Log).
But If I call the script from a cell (in the cell: `=get_id_pdf()`) of my Google-Sheet, I get the error:

> "*You do not have permission to call getFilesByName*" (see image)

I have of course all the authorization to access to this file (it is in my own drive, and the file havs been created by me).

Does somebody have an idea ?

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom function throws a "You do not have the permission required to setValue" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933019/custom-function-throws-a-you-do-not-have-the-permission-required-to-setvalue-e)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make calls to services that require user authorization as an anonymous user, which is what custom functions execute as. You will need to put the behavior into a custom menu, or a sidebar so that it can be authorized by the user.

[Authorization Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts)

[Custom Function Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

> If your custom function throws the error message ***"You do not have
>   permission to call X service."***, the service requires user authorization
>   and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

Comment: I am sorry. I have read the document from the URLs but I just don't understand what to do.

Comment: You need to put the behavior in a custom menu or a sidebar. There is documentation on how to dot his, google `google spreadsheet custom sidebar` or `google spreadsheet custom menu`. My answer answers why you are receiving this error, if you want to know how to make a custom menu or sidebar then ask a new question related to what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Do you think it's possible to call a custom menu function (that makes the request to google drive app) from a cell to work around that issue?