# Count the number of cells that have the text strikethrough

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

I would like to create a custom function to count the number of strikethrough text. Would it be possible to create a script to perform this operation?

For the moment, I managed to create a script that counts the cell number with the strikethrough text, but I have to modify my script each time for a different range, and I can not create a custom function that count the number of cells that have the text strikethrough.

Here is my script:

The result is in the L20 and the control in the script

```
// Count the number of cells that are barred
function fontLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var plage = "E4:E11"
  var range = sheet.getRange(plage);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      if (cell.getFontLine() === 'line-through')
        x++;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("L20").setValue(x);
  return x;
}
```

Comment: What You mean with "can not create a custom function"? In google-sheets You will only get the seleted cells values, sadly. But You could change the argument to the function to a tring with sourrounding quotes I assume - or put the range as text into another filed - and use that to find the range. Or possibly use named ranges.

Comment: Hello @Psychomecano, I published an answer. Let me know if that's what you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom function throws a "You do not have the permission required to setValue" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933019/custom-function-throws-a-you-do-not-have-the-permission-required-to-setvalue-e)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use `setValue` in a custom function but, as you already figured out, it's possible to get the result you are looking for by using a "regular script" (running it from a menu, by clicking an image, from the script editor, etc.)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 0):

### Modifications of your code

1. It now uses [`getActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveSheet()) to obtain the sheet from where the function is called, and [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) to obtain the whole range in  the sheet where there is data.
2. It uses [`getFontLines()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontLines()) on the whole range instead of iterating cell-per-cell and calling [`getFontLine()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontline) to every single one of them. This results in a way more efficient code (see: [Best Practices - Minimize calls to other services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)).
3. Removed `setValue()` call. If you want the result of this custom function to be placed in the `L20` cell, simply modify its contents for this formula: `=fontLine()`. The value returned by the custom function will be set as the cell's value.

```js
// Count the number of cells in the sheet that are barred
function fontLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var fontLines = range.getFontLines();
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < fontLines.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < fontLines[i].length; j++) {
      if (fontLines[i][j] === 'line-through')
        x++;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

### Example execution

[image: example of the execution]

### Disclaimers

- Custom functions are executed upon writing them into a cell. Afterwards, their result is cached so that less resources are used. That means that if you add or remove strike-through's from your sheet, you will have to remove and re-insert the custom function in your cell.