# Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 1)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a project with two scripts, that is bound to a Google spreadsheet.
The first script opens the UI

```
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

const TOKEN_OLD = 'api.token_old';

function onOpen(){

  ui.createMenu('CREDENZIALI')
  .addItem('Imposta TOKEN', 'setToken')
  .addToUi();
}

function setToken(){
  var scriptValue = ui.prompt('Per favore inserisci il token.' , ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  userProperties.setProperty(TOKEN_OLD, scriptValue.getResponseText());
}
```

And the second one does the business logic and implements a custom function that is meant to be used into the spreadsheet.

```
function getFromApi(book_id,dato) {...}
```

Obviously, this API is behind authentication and I don't want to hardcode a token into the script, so I've created the first UI in order to let the end-user manage it at runtime.

The UI works flawlessly but when I try to invoke the custom function, I get this error:
[image]

I am the owner of the files. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `SpreadsheetApp.getUi();` inside `onOpen()` and `setToken()` separately.

The following script works as standalone:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

const TOKEN_OLD = 'api.token_old';

function onOpen(){
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('CREDENZIALI')
  .addItem('Imposta TOKEN', 'setToken')
  .addToUi();
}

function setToken(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var scriptValue = ui.prompt('Per favore inserisci il token.' , ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  userProperties.setProperty(TOKEN_OLD, scriptValue.getResponseText());
}
```

However, you can not use a custom formula to call this function. See related articles:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=fr-FR)
- [Custom function throws a "You do not have the permission required to setValue" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933019/custom-function-throws-a-you-do-not-have-the-permission-required-to-setvalue-e)