# Displaying a prompt and getting user input in Google Apps script bound to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, user-input

I have an Google sheet with some apps script code in it and I am trying to make it interactive by displaying a prompt and getting some user input. I have added a simple function to test that this works:

```
function displayPrompt() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please enter a name for your report:");
  
    Logger.log(result.getResponseText());
     
};
```

When I run it, I get the error:
"Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context."

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks Annette

Comment: see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809904/exception-cannot-call-spreadsheetapp-getui-from-this-context-line-1) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270842/exception-cannot-call-spreadsheetapp-getui-from-this-context-line-2-file)

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to run it from the script editor.  That' what "context" means.  Add a menu item [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getUi()) and try to run it from the menu while your are in the spreadsheet "context".

Comment: It runs just fine when run from the script editor

Comment: I was trying to run it from the script editor, which is when I got the error, It works if I add it as a menu item so I'm going to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run it using a trigger it works as soon as I open the file

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please enter a name for your report:");

  Logger.log(result.getResponseText());
}
```