# You do not have permission to call openById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon, google-sheets-custom-function

Problem:  When I run the script, Google tells me,

> You do not have permission to call openById

I had copied a script from another one of my Google spreadsheets and changed the **target_ssKey** variable's cell reference and created properly-sized Named Ranges in both the Source and Target spreadsheets.

Google Apps Script documentation says nothing about reasons why it might not be working:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById%28String%29

Another Google Apps Script documentation says that it *should* work for me because I invoke it from a custom menu:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

The second link above says:

> If your custom function throws the error message ***You do not have
>   permission to call X service.***, the service requires user authorization
>   and thus cannot be used in a custom function.
>
> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu
>   that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom
>   function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user
>   for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps
>   Script services.

I tried putting the function into a "Custom Functions" project and then into an "Add-on" project, but still got the same error message.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to make this work?

Here is my exact code:

```
function exportData_SStoSS() {
    //  Get the source data.
    var source_ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var data = source_ss.getRangeByName("exportData").getValues();

    //  Identify the target.
    var controls_sh = source_ss.getSheetByName("Controls");
    var target_ssKey = controls_sh.getRange('C2').getValue();
    var target_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(target_ssKey);

    //  Paste the data to the target.
    target_ss.getRangeByName("importData").setValues(data);
};
```

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details to reproduce the problem specially when the function is called from a custom menu and from an add/on (custom functions can't execute methods that require permissions)

Comment: Possible duplicate [No permission to call msgBox in Google Apps Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10506105/1595451) (while the error message is not exactly the same the cause is and that question is older)

Answer (score 39):

I thought that I would throw in a similar issue that I had which brought me to this question, where I received the error `You don't have permission to call by openById`.

In my case I was trying to call functions from `translate.gs` which I copied from this example:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs

Note that at the top of `translate.gs`

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 *
 * The above comment directs Apps Script to limit the scope of file
 * access for this add-on. It specifies that this add-on will only
 * attempt to read or modify the files in which the add-on is used,
 * and not all of the user's files. The authorization request message
 * presented to users will reflect this limited scope.
 */
```

The culprit here is the `@OnlyCurrentDoc` comment. See here for reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Removing `@OnlyCurrentDoc` fixed this issue for me

Comment: Removing @OnlyCurrentDoc also fixed this issue for me

Comment: well, I do not have @OnlyCurrentDoc tag in my app's script, yet I am getting this error.

Comment: I removed @OnlyCurrentDoc and it did NOT fix this issue for me!

Comment: I added `@NotOnlyCurrentDoc` in both of my scripts (menu and macro code). It fixed it

Answer (score 22):

I could resolved this issue with this autorization guide of google developers.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes

This entry It's necesary in json file.

```
 "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
```

Comment: this helped me solve my issue with, need to add the scope it's complaining about to `appsscript.json` in the project root. If you don't see this file, you'll need to go to Project Settings (in the left navver) and check the 'Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor' checkbox.

Comment: This helped solve my issue as well.  I just added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets to the appsscript.json, ran the function with the new functionality and it opened the permissions dialog.

Answer (score 18):

I found this official note about [Using Google Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_services) which I believe clears up what caused the issue.

> Custom functions can call certain Google Apps Script services to perform more complex tasks. Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data, specifically the following:
>
> Spreadsheet | Read only (can use most `get*()` methods, but not `set*()`).
> Cannot open other spreadsheets (`SpreadsheetApp.openById()` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`).
>
> If your custom function throws the error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.
>
> To use a service other than those listed above, create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.

Answer (score 4):

Had this same issue and came to share my solution. In my case I had two spreadsheets, call them A and B. Both used scripts bound to each respective spreadsheet. Spreadsheet B was able to write data to a tab of spreadsheet A. But Spreadsheet A kept getting the "You do not have permission to call openById" error when trying to read from spreadsheet B. I then tried adding it as a custom menu item but still the same issue.

The solution in my case turned out to be really simple. I created a new unbound script in script.google.com that calls both spreadsheets using openById. The first time running put a smile on my face as it asked for authorization. Thereafter smooth sailing.

Answer (score 2):

The method `openById` can be called from a "Blank Project" but not a "Custom Functions in Sheets" nor a "Google Sheets Add-on" project.

I thought a "Blank Project" would create a project that was not connected to my spreadsheet, but I was wrong. The Blank Project is connected to my spreadsheet.  The other types of projects that I tried to use seem to be limited-scope versions of script projects, not able to carry out some GAS methods.

Comment: Is there an official source for these information ?

Comment: Best I can offer you in terms of an offical source is to do this: Open the sheet, click Tools > 'script editor'. The page you are taken to is for that sheet's "Add-on" functions. This option should not work if you made a Blank Project (but you will also lose access to things like onEdit using that approach)